# DiscretePlot3D: Part specification is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers

Tags: plotting, matrix

I want to plot a 3D histogram of a matrix and I am using this line:

```
DiscretePlot3D[lmat[[x, y]], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

where `lmat` is the matrix.
The output is correct, but I receive the following error line:

> Part::pspec: Part specification x is neither a machine-sized integer nor a list of machine-sized integers. >>

Where am I making a mistake? The line doesn't show up if I replace `lmat[[x, y]]` with a "standard" function such as `Sin[x, y]` or if I use a function defined by myself such as `f[x_, y_] := Sin[x + y]`.

The line appear again if I use functions which involve matrices:

```
amat = {{1, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, 2, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 2}};
h[x_, y_] := amat[[x, y]]
DiscretePlot3D[h[x, y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the behavior you observe in my version of Mathematica (10.2 on Win7-64), so I assume that you might be working on an older version. It would be interesting if you could add your version and platform to your question for reference.

---

Nevertheless, in my opinion the problem seems to be that the plotting function is **attempting to evaluate its argument symbolically first**. At that stage $x$ and $y$ have not been assigned a numerical value yet, so `Part` (i.e. `[[...]]`) throws an error because only integers or lists can be used as part specifications.

`DiscretePlot3D` then proceeds with numerical evaluation by assigning appropriate values to $x$ and $y$, which works fine and generates your plot.

You can force numerical evaluation with a user defined function:

```
f[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := lmat[[x, y]]
DiscretePlot3D[f[x, y], {x, 1, 3}, {y, 1, 3}, ExtentSize -> Full]
```

Take a look at this FAQ for more details about the powers of `NumeriQ`:
[User-defined functions, numerical approximation, and NumericQ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/193).

---

More appropriately to your situation, and since `Part` is only supposed to work on integers, you can further restrict the function to evaluate only when the arguments are integers, as suggested by [Guess Who It Is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50) in a comment below:

```
f[x_Integer, y_Integer] := lmat[[x, y]]
```

Comment: Even better: since `Part[]` is not expected to deal with fractional arguments, just do `f[x_Integer, y_Integer] := (* stuff *)`.

Comment: @Guess good point. I added that definition to the answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `BarChart3D` using the "Grid" option for `ChartLayout` may be more useful for your aim, e.g.

```
mat = {{1, -1, 0, 0}, {-1, 2, 0, -1}, {0, 0, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1, 2}};
BarChart3D[mat, ChartLayout -> "Grid",
 ChartLabels -> {Range[4], Range[4]},
 LabelingFunction -> (Placed[Style[#, Red, Bold], Above] &), 
 ChartStyle -> Blue]
```

[image]

or just `ListPointPlot3D`, e.g.

```
ListPointPlot3D[mat, Filling -> Axis, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]]
```

[image]

Comment: I think that they are both good solutions, but can anyone explain me the origin of the error message I riceived?

Comment: @Francesco MarcoB has provided a clear answer...I have nothing to add...apologies for delay...timezones